# Finding Tab position from another Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

In my fragment_whatsHappening I have a tabbed viewPagerAdapter which displays the days of the week.
(Today,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun)
Every tab will inflate fragment_schedules_view which contains a recyclerView displaying tasks to do on that day. 
fragment_schedules_view.class contains the recyclerView

```
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.schedulesPager);
    SchedulesViewPagerAdapter tabAdapter = new SchedulesViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    // Add Fragments to adapter one by one
    tabAdapter.addFragment(new fragment_schedules_view(), "Today");
    tabAdapter.addFragment(new fragment_schedules_view(), "Tue");
    tabAdapter.addFragment(new fragment_schedules_view(), "Wed");
    tabAdapter.addFragment(new fragment_schedules_view(), "Thu");
    tabAdapter.addFragment(new fragment_schedules_view(), "Fri");
    tabAdapter.addFragment(new fragment_schedules_view(), "Sat");
    tabAdapter.addFragment(new fragment_schedules_view(), "Sun");
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleTabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

In my fragment_schedules_view.class is there a way to get the tabAdapter position from the fragment_whatsHappening.class?

Comment: You really only need to run code in a fragment if it's the one the user is currently looking at.  Do you really just need the fragment to know when the user has swiped over to this fragment?

Comment: Yeah I do. It's used to work out the date so the recyclerView retrieves information from the relevant date child. (the database childs I'm retrieving from are formatted like this (04-06-2018)) the tabs are used to retrieve data from the next 7 days

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in ViewPager `getCurrentItem` which return int, position of currently viewed page.

Answer (score 0):

Used a OnTabSelectedListener and use an interface from my your fragment to update the index every time the tab position has changed.

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        //reference your method from your other fragment. In my case the 
       // onTabSchedulesChanged method from my fragment_schedules_view.class



        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
});
```